# Adding bulk data to mysql database

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have a console program where the user scans in serial numbers, and those serial numbers get added to a database.

```
const mysql = require('mysql2');
const read = require('readline-sync');

const conn = new mysql.createConnection(config);

conn.connect(
function(err){
    if(err){
        throw err;
    }
    else{
        console.log("Connection Established");
        while(1){
            var sn = read.question('Scan in serial number: ');
            conn.query('INSERT INTO test (serial) VALUES (?);',
            [sn], function(err, results, fields){
                if (err){
                    throw err;
                }
                else{
                    console.log("Added stuff");
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
);
```

When the code runs it successfully connects to the database but queries the database.  It continually prompts for user input.

Alternatively, I tried storing serial numbers in an array and then loops through it adding each element, like this.

```
const mysql = require('mysql2');
const read = require('readline-sync');

var array = [];
var sn = " ";
while (1) {
    sn = read.question('Scan in serial number, or enter "done" if finished scanning');
    if (sn == "done") {
        break;
    }
    array.push(sn);
}

conn.connect(
    function (err) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
        else {
            console.log("Connection Established");
            array.forEach(function (sn) {
                conn.query('INSERT INTO test (serial) VALUES (?);',
                    [sn], function (err, results, fields) {
                        if (err) {
                            throw err;
                        }
                        else {
                            console.log("Added stuff");
                        }
                    });
            });
        }
    }
);
```

In this case, it works inconsistently.  Sometimes it works fine, and other times  it fails to connect and throws a timeout error.  Is there a better way to accomplish this and/or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: If you try to concatenate all queries and then execute a single string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var promises = []
function dbOp(value) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      conn.query('INSERT INTO test (serial) VALUES (?);',
                [value], function (err, results, fields) {
                    if (err) {
                        return reject(err)
                    }
                    else {
                        console.log("Added stuff"); 
                        resolve(results)
                    }
  }
}




conn.connect(function(err){
    if(err){
        throw err;
    }
    else{
        for (i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
            promises.push(dbOp(array[i]));
        }
    }
});

  Promise.all(promises)
      .then((results) => {
        console.log("done", results);
      })
      .catch((e) => {
          console.log(e)
      });
```

Comment: It behaves exactly the same way as before.

Comment: @ajjohnson190 oh , I looked it too quick and thought it was a promise , so basically you need to wrap your callback with native promise and then loop through array push into promise chain.

Comment: That works, if you don't mind could you explain what that does?  I don't quite understand.

Comment: @ajjohnson190 so to handle db operation , you are using `.query` which is a `callback`. I don't know if you can use `async/await` so I wrapped your `callback` in a native `promise` which is another way to handle async operation and then push into a `Promise.all` which resolves all the promise you add from loop through the array. if you need more please google `callback, promise, async/await` ways to handle async operations.

Answer (score 0):

This might be caused by short idle timeout setting in your mysql server. `client.connect()` is pretty much a no-op in mysql2, it connects immediately when you call `mysql.createConnection()`. You can change order to establish connection only after all data is collected:

```
const mysql = require('mysql2');
const read = require('readline-sync');

var array = [];
var sn = ' ';
while (1) {
  sn = read.question('Scan in serial number, or enter "done" if finished scanning');
  if (sn == 'done') {
    const conn = mysql.createConnection(config);
    array.forEach(function(sn) {
      conn.query('INSERT INTO test (serial) VALUES (?);', [sn], function(err, results, fields) {
        if (err) {
          throw err;
        } else {
          console.log('Added stuff');
        }
      });
    });
  }
  array.push(sn);
}
```